# Prime divisors of $n^3+3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

find all prime numbers $p$ for which there exists an integer $n$ such that $p|n^3+3$

In $p=3k+2$ then by Senderov's lemma , $n^3$ gives all remainders including $-3$ also for $p=3$ it's obvious that $n=3$ works

If $p=3k+1$ : let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$ . By Fermat $p\mid g^{3k}-1$ and since $g$ is a primitive root, $p$ doesn't divide $g^k-1$ thus $p\mid g^{2k}+g^k+1$ therefore $p\mid (2g^k+1)^2+3$

So we have $n^3=(2g^k+1)^2$

So $g^k=(n^3-1)/2 \pmod p$.

So we have  $(n^3-1)/2$ its powers produces only $3$ different remainders. Further,let $L$ be an integer whose powers produce $3$ different remainders, write $L=g^s$ so $3k\mid 3s$ and $k,2k\mid 3s$ obviously $L\equiv g^k\pmod p$

So the question is equivalent to prime numbers $p=3k+1$ for which there is an integer $n$ such that $(n^3+1)/2$ its 3rd power is 1(mod p) but non of its 1st and 2nd power is not 1(mod p)

Also put $n=x^2$ it becomes $(x^3)^2+3$ since all non $3$ prime divisors of $a^2+3$ are in the form $3m+1$ so are all non $3$ prime divisors of $x^6+3$ by Schur's lemma $x^6+3$
Has infinitely many prime divisors so the $3k+1$  desired prime numbers is infinite!

Comment: Do you have a question here?

Comment: You have that $n^3=(2g^k+1)^2$ mod p. It seems like the square on the right side then suddenly disappears...

Comment: Try https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity